# How do I fix my jQuery onclick won't remove a link & each function failed to load current number

Tags: jquery

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/LW5pw/

```
<a href="#" onclick="removeShipping('#shipping-block-id'); return false;">Remove</a>
```

Remove link is not working to remove the current `shipping-block-id` div.

Also on `each(function(i)` won't generate the current++ block number for `name='shipping-price2'`, `name='shipping-price3'`

```
$newshipping.children("div").children("input").each(function(i) {
   var $currentElem = $(this);
   $currentElem.attr("name", $currentElem.attr("name") + current);
   $currentElem.attr("id", $currentElem.attr("id") + current);
});
```

Let me know how do I fix this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `shipping-template` should be

```
<div id="shipping-template" class="hide">
  <div>
    input..
  </div>
</div>
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/LW5pw/1/